# Do Canon's TS lenses work on Metabones?

Tags: canon, sony, adapter, tilt-shift

I have Metabones IV on an A7RII and am interested in Canon's T&S lenses. Will they work without issues?

Answer (score 1):

I think yes, as Metabones IV support electronic diaphragm activation and the Canon T&S lenses are manual focus.